# Opening and closing of gate based on value returned by a function in Python

Tags: python, arduino

I was writing a piece of code to open/close a gate, based on the value returned by a function. The gate is linked to an Arduino and a Python program. When I run the function `blinktheLED`, it will print `yes,open the gate`. The function `code_controlling_gate`, takes the value returned by function `blinktheLED` and works accordingly.

Now what I want is, as long as the function returns `TRUE`, the gate should open. Unfortunately, when I run the code the gate only opens once. The Python code and Arduino code is shown below.

```
set_accepted_list = set(['1','3','112','29'])
set_list_LED_id   = set(['1','3'])
def blinktheLED(set_accepted_list,set_list_LED_id):
    if len(set_accepted_list &  set_list_LED_id) >0:
        print"yes,open the gate"                  #it will print, when i run the code
        return True
    else:
        print"no,donot open the gate"
        return False 
def code_controlling_gate(True):
    connected = False
    ser = serial.Serial("COM11",9600)  
    while not connected:
       serin = ser.read()
       connected = True
    ser.write('1')
    while ser.read() == '1':
       ser.read()
    ser.close()
```

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
Serial.write('1');
}
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    delay(500);
    Serial.read();
    }
    else{
      Serial.available()==0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in words what each of the Arduino loop, blinktheLED, and code_controlling_gate are meant to do.  I suspect if you do that you will see the problem.